# ASP.NET Web Application compilation on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have created a project using web forms. and uploaded on server and every thing works fine.

now when i make some changes in code behind files (.cs) and upload them on server its not doing any changes unless i upload the .Dll file in bin.

its totally opposite to classic web site when we do changes on fly and it works fine on server.

can we do the same in web form applications ?

please help!

Comment: For the asp.net app to re-compile on the server you need to recycle the app pool for the specific app.

Answer (score 0):

You can recycle the app pool in the IIS User Interface or use commandline. See more here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770764(v=ws.10).aspx

In addition, you can setup IIS to recycle app pool using different kinds of conditions:
- At a scheduled time
- After an elapsed time
- After reaching a number of requests
- After reaching a virtual memory threshold
- After reaching a used memory threshold

See more here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(v=ws.10).aspx